# animated closing flash message on bootstrap rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap with rails to generate flash message, i also have the following JS code:

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.alert').slideUp(400);
    }, 1800);
});
```

Render fash in partial

```
<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= flash_class_name(message_type) %> alert-dismissable">
    <span><%= message %></span>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

the code seems to work just fine, except the animation for flash message generated from Application Controller like:

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to main_app.root_path, :alert => exception.message
end
```

animation generated elsewhere from Application Controller works just fine,i don't know why it doesn't work in this case most of the time and how to fix that

Comment: what is the default state for `.alert` is **hidden** or it **shows**. can you share styling for `.alert` as well

Comment: this can happen if `.alert` is **hidden** that's why asked you to add styling.

Comment: it shows properly using bootstrap styling, but the animation not (only from App Controller)

Comment: perhaps i should open an issue in rails github